# Avoid X axis labels repetition in Altair chart

Tags: python, data-science, data-visualization, altair

So I got this chart which displays a time series in X.Axis using yearmonth('date'):T. The thing is, it duplicates the labels to fill the spaces, but I don't want that behaviour. I'd like a single label each time. How can I do this?

[image: The chart]

```
example df:
ID      date        total
3425    2022-01-04  30
15161   2022-01-12  1730
18192   2022-01-13  1526
21014   2022-01-21  99
24692   2022-02-07  28
30163   2022-02-21  175
31531   2022-02-22  446
34467   2022-03-22  57
34880   2022-03-23  500
35144   2022-03-30  41
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example to facilitate for others helping you.

Comment: added to description

Comment: Thanks for adding a sample of your data. A minimal reproducible example also entails adding the minimal code to reproduce your example as detailed here https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the type of the date column to **O (Ordinal)** if you are using **T(Time)**.

```python
chart = (
alt.Chart(source).mark_line().encode(
    x=alt.X("Fecha:O", timeUnit="yearmonth", title="Fecha"),
    y=alt.Y("Monto:Q", stack=None)
)
```